# OWIN Startup class not detected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, owin, startup, app-startup

I was trying to implement OWIN WS Federation in an existing application. It's a web application in asp .net VB.
I have added all the references from the Nugetpackages
[List of refernces added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM1nt.png)

Then I added the startup class in 2 files as a `Partial` class.

StartupAuth.vb:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Extensions
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation
Imports Owin

Partial Public Class Startup
    Private Shared realm As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Wtrealm")
    Private Shared adfsMetadata As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ADFSMetadata")

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(New WsFederationAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .Wtrealm = realm,
            .MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
        })
        ' This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and Startup.vb:

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Owin

<Assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(GetType(Startup))>

Partial Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        ConfigureAuth(app)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I also added these two lines in the webconfig:

```xml
<add key="owin:HandleAllRequests" value="true" />
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Startup.vb" />
```

If anyone has any idea about what is happening please let me know.

thanks in advance.

As I dont have a namespace for the project and the startup files I have not added it in the config file. When I try to run the application I get the following error:

[Chrome error while running the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ojsP.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not providing the full name of the **Startup** class including its namespace. Even if you don't use a namespace in your class files there is a default global one already configured.

The default namespace is defined in your project settings as *Root namespace*. It is the same as your project name. Check your project properties. It will be in the *Root namespace* field.

Now if your project is called *SomeProject* you could configure using one of these options:

1. Using the attribute: `<Assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(GetType(SomeProject.Startup))>`
   (Also remove the `owin:AppStartup` key in your web.config file)
2. Using the web.config key: `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="SomeProject.Startup" />`

Note how I removed the ".vb" part as the key expects a full class name and not a file name.

Using the web.config overrides the value in the Attribute. So you only need to use one of them and not both in your case.

you can check [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) to better understand how OWIN detects the **Startup** class.